# Insert/replace/merge values from one dataframe to another

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-merge

I have two dataframes like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID1':['A','B','C','D','E','F'],
                    'ID2':['0','10','80','0','0','0']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID1':['A','D','E','F'],
                    'ID2':['50','30','90','50'],
                    'aa':['1','2','3','4']})
```

[image: df1,df2]

I want to insert `ID2` in `df2` into `ID2` in `df1`, and at the same time insert `aa` into `df1` according to `ID1` to obtain a new dataframe like this:

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame({'ID1':['A','B','C','D','E','F'],
                       'ID2':['50','10','80','30','90','50'],
                         'aa':['1','NaN','NaN','2','3','4']})
```

[image: df_result]

I've tried to use merge, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) on the DataFrame after setting the index to ID1:

```
(df2.set_index('ID1')  # values of df2 have priority in case of overlap
    .combine_first(df1.set_index('ID1')) # add missing values from df1
    .reset_index()     # reset ID1 as column
)
```

output:

```
  ID1 ID2   aa
0   A  50    1
1   B  10  NaN
2   C  80  NaN
3   D  30    2
4   E  90    3
5   F  50    4
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with [`Series.combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
In [568]: x = df1.merge(df2, on='ID1', how='left')
In [571]: x['ID2'] = x.ID2_y.combine_first(x.ID2_x)
In [574]: x.drop(['ID2_x', 'ID2_y'], 1, inplace=True)

In [575]: x
Out[575]: 
  ID1   aa ID2
0   A    1  50
1   B  NaN  10
2   C  NaN  80
3   D    2  30
4   E    3  90
5   F    4  50
```

**OR** use [`df.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with [`df.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html):

```
In [568]: x = df1.merge(df2, on='ID1', how='left')
In [597]: x['ID2'] = x.filter(like='ID2').ffill(axis=1)['ID2_y']
In [599]: x.drop(['ID2_x', 'ID2_y'], 1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: You don't need the `merge`, [`combine_first` is sufficient if you use the proper index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70958995/16343464) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
new_df = df1.assign(ID2=df1['ID2'].replace('0', np.nan)).merge(df2, on='ID1', how='left').pipe(lambda g: g.assign(ID2=g.filter(like='ID2').bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]).drop(['ID2_x', 'ID2_y'], axis=1))
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
  ID1   aa ID2
0   A    1  50
1   B  NaN  10
2   C  NaN  80
3   D    2  30
4   E    3  90
5   F    4  50
```